# Change baseUrl on fly ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I want execute some ember routing from another domain:
Example:

```
m.site.com/foo
site.com/path/to/ember/bar
```

So I should change root path on the fly depends on which domain script executed

I try add `rootURL` to `Ember.Router`

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'hash'
    rootURL: '/path/to/ember/'
});
```

and change app-config-from-meta.js in ember-cli

```
    try {
      var metaName = prefix + '/config/environment';
      var rawConfig = Ember['default'].$('meta[name="' + metaName + '"]').attr('content');
      var config = JSON.parse(unescape(rawConfig));

   if (window.location.href.indexOf('m.') !== -1) {
            config.baseURL = '/path/to/ember/';
            config.locationType = 'hash';
      }
    console.log(config);
      return { 'default': config };
    }
    catch(err) {
      throw new Error('Could not read config from meta tag with name "' + metaName + '".');
    }
```

but it's not help.

**Update:**

Problem was in a `'<base href="' + baseURL + '">'` tag which inserted during build. So, as  understand I need create alternatively index file like `index.html` and `index_bar.html`. What the easier way do to it?

Update:
My realization:
Into `broccoli-config-replace` action `process` added

```
if (filePath.indexOf('index_bar.html') > 0){
        var tmpConfig = config;
        tmpConfig.baseURL = config._chatBaseURL;
        tmpConfig.locationType = config._chatLocationType;
        this.processFile(tmpConfig, filePath, destPath);
    } else {
        this.processFile(config, filePath, destPath);
    }
```

`index.html` works with `auto` routing and base `/`

`index_bar.html` works with `hash` routing and base `/path/to/ember/`

Any better solution? Thanks

Comment: You may set baseURL in environment.js to null to prevent ember-cli from generating a base tag.